# Switch between two parallax backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to switch between two parallax background using waypoints. All works well in Chrome, but the problem appear on other browsers.

- Firefox:, when I switch between background-images, the next background will appear for a second over all other elements on the site.
- Safari, have a lot of lag.

**Edited** working example now:
http://codepen.io/rajjejosefsson/pen/vXVYNL

```
.background_fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.background_fill:before {
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    content: " ";
    position: fixed;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
    will-change: transform;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.background-render { 
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Mobile-Wallpapers-HD-640x400.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    will-change: transform;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just removed the params from show() and hide() functions and it started to work fine in FF and Safari.

[Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) functions don't accept such argument. `.background_fill` isn't a valid duration.

The resulting JavaScript:

```
$(".background_fill").hide();

$(document).ready(function() {

  /* new hidden background */

  $('.js_show_new_bg').waypoint(function(direction) {

    if (direction === "down") {
      $(".background_fill").show();
    } else {
      $(".background_fill").hide();
    }
  }, {
    offset: '1%'
  });

});
```

Also you can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to simplify your code:

```
$(".background_fill").toggle(direction === "down"); // true = show, false = hide
```

Instead of this code:

```
if (direction === "down") {
  $(".background_fill").show();
} else {
  $(".background_fill").hide();
}
```